# $(I+iA)$ is invertible proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, with a positive definite hermitian product. Let $A:V\to V$ be a hermitian operator. Show that $I+iA$ and $I-iA$ are invertible.[Hint: If $v\neq 0$,show that $||(I+iA)v||\neq 0$.]

SOLUTION. We contend that $\ker(I+iA)={0}$. We have

$\langle(I+iA)v,(I+iA)v\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle+\langle v,iAv\rangle+\langle iAv,v\rangle+\langle iAv,iAv\rangle\\=\langle v,v\rangle-i\langle v,Av\rangle+i\langle Av,v\rangle+\langle Av,Av\rangle\\=\langle v,v\rangle+\langle Av,Av\rangle$

***Solutions Manual to Lang´s Linear Algebra,by Rmai Shakarchi***

Since the product is positive definite, our contention is proved. Theorem 3.3 of chapter III guarantees that $I+iA$ is invertible. The same argument shows that $I-iA$ is invertible.

Theorem 3.3. of chapter III

> Theorem:Let $L:V\to W$ be a linear map. Assume that $\dim V=\dim W$.
>
> If $\ker L={0}$ or if $Im L=W$, then $L$ is bijective.***Linear Algebra,by Serge Lang***

**Questions:**

For a transformation to be invertible it needs to be an isomorphism. $\langle(I+iA)v,(I+iA)v\rangle $is not the map $A:V\to V$. It is instead a map $V\to\mathbb{R}$. How can it be proven that $I+ia$ is an isomorphism and hence invertible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is enough to show A has real eigenvalues...anyway, the point is that you have shown some norm is nonzero and that therefore the vector you put in was not in the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A map $T:\Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$ is invertible if and only if it has a trivial kernel, which is true if and only if $\|Tv\| = 0 \implies \|v\| = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: choosing a suitable basis (which exists because $A$ is Hermitian), can you show $I+A^2$ has eigenvalues $\ge 1$? How does $X^{-1}=Y(XY)^{-1}$ then solve the problem?

Comment: I have not covered eigenvalues yet.